# WebClient error when using a thread in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, webclient

I'm having a **very** weird error using the WebClient class in .NET 4.

The app simply downloads some files off the internet and provides output on a textbox (the GUI is WPF). The method that does this is the following:

```
void DownloadFiles(object files) {
    var fileL = (List<string>) files;
    foreach (string url in fileL)
    {
        byte[] data;
        using (var k = new WebClient())
        {
             data = k.DownloadData(url);
        }
        //Bunch of irrelevant code goes here...
    }
}
```

(I added the using while trying to divine [yes I'm that desperate/ignorant] a solution, the problem happens even if the webclient is declared and initialized outside the foreach loop)

Now the problem appears only when I'm executing this method on a thread separate from the WPF UI main thread. If it is executed on the UI thread then it works perfectly. When a new thread is created with:

```
Thread t = new Thread(DownloadFiles);
t.Start(files);
```

The first time the code goes into the loop it will work, but when its the second pass inside the loop, I will always receive a TargetParameterCountException.

I can't make any sense of this error. Any help is very much appreciated.

**edit**
Here are the Exception Details:

```
Exception.Message  = "Parameter count mismatch."
Exception.InnerException = null
Exception.Source = " mscorlib"
```

The StackTrace follows:

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()     at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at FileDownloader.App.Main() in d:\mis documentos\visual studio 2010\Projects\OneMangaDownloader\FileDownloader\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Please post more details on the error (message, stacktrace, InnerException details...)

Comment: Added the info you requested Thomas, thx for any help

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a bug in WebClient where it always puts the call on the UI thread. Not sure if this is causing the issues.

[For more info read this post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/10.aspx).

Comment: I think that's a Windows Mobile restriction maybe?  Also the 6 connection limit.  If not...  Wow...